# How to fix PHP (Twitter API) that won't render in local host

Tags: php, html, json, twitter

Following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPnGB7a7dO0) to finish off a client that returns tweets that match a search query. Using PHP to handle the Twitter Standard Search API (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html), my HTML renders but my PHP causes a handle request error. It's my first project building on an API and my first project with PHP.

Checked the App tokens to make sure they match the ones given by twitter - they do

Changed the directory of the `twitteroauth.php` file into my MAMP (local server environment) `htdocs` folder

Played with the code from the tutorial - stil nothing.

```
<?php
$consumer = "-";
$consumersecret = "-";
$accesstoken = "-";
$accesstokensecret = "-";

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

?> /* with this block of code nothing renders in browser */

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitterSearchClientStyle.css">
</head>
<title>Search Tweets</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>
<div align="center" class="header">
  <img tag id="logo" src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/91-911613_white-twitter-bird-transparent-background-clipart.png" alt=“the Twitter bird">
  <h1>Search Tweets!</h1>
  <p>We can bet someone has tweeted about it!</p>
</div>

<div align="center" class=“body”>
  <form class="tweet-form" action="" method="post">
  <input id="input-text" type="text" name=“keyword"/><br><br>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="GET TWEETS">
  </form>
</div>

<div align="center" id="tweets">
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['keyword{'])){
    $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='.$_POST['keyword'].'&result_type=recent&count=20');
    foreach ($tweets as $tweet){
        foreach ($tweet as $t){
        echo '<img src="'.$t ->user->profile_image_url.'"/>'.$t->text.'<br>.';
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
    </div> /* this is a problem? */
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/awTYJ.jpg - this is what I want to happen

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnaFP.jpg - this is what happens with the first block of PHP (before the html)

Comment: Is it wise to publish all those secret tokens?

Comment: It's only for a personal project to learn some PHP & people post them all over youtube. Although I can edit to remove.

Comment: @James: those tokens are still visible in the edit history. It'd be a good idea to invalidate them with the provider and generate new ones.